# Tailwind CSS Background Image not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, tailwind-css, vite

There are few other similar questions regarding this and i have check them and double checked them against my own code and i cannot figure out whats happening. NO errors in console, except some warnings insignificant warnings: "unknown at rule @tailwind".

The problem is that image will not render.

To be fair i'm a bit new.

AppLayout.jsx

```
    import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
    
    import Header from '../components/Header'
    import Footer from '../components/Footer'
    
    const AppLayout = () => {
      return (
        <div className="bg-background h-screen">
          <Header />
          <main className="grow">
            <Outlet />
          </main>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      )
    }

export default AppLayout
```

Tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'background': "url('./public/tractor.jpg')",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I should add that within the prettier ignore file, i added tailwind.config.js file
to prevent it from correcting any of the quotes.

Anyone know whats going on here?

Tailwind Docs:

[tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image)

[Screen shot of my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIBdh.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this it works for me

```
export default {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
   theme: {
      extend: {
         backgroundImage: {
             'background': "url('/src/tractor.jpg')",
         },
      },
   },
  plugins: [],

}

<div className="bg-background bg-cover bg-no-repet bg-center">
      <Header />
      <main className="grow">
        <Outlet />
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
```

Comment: i gave it a shot, moved the img to src as per the url you provided and copy pasted. Still nothing.